# List all udev rules (e.g. for a device)?

Tags: udev

I want to know how I can list all udev rules.

I know that in they can be potentially stored as lines (one line = one rule) in `*.rules` files in these directories

```
/etc/udev/rules.d
/lib/udev/rules.d
/run/udev/rules.d
/var/run/udev/rules.d
```

Therefore I though I can find all rules by simple concating all the `*.rules` files in those directories. This seems not to be working (because some rules are executed which I cannot find anyware as rules in these directories).

At best I thought that there is a command to the udevadm interface which will let me print out all the rules that udev currently has.

To be certain I did a review of `man udevadm` and especially the part about `udevadm info [parameters]` does not seem to yield any result.

Given that udev allows for a multitude of files and rules all targeted for the very same device, it is frustrating not to know an efficient/feasible way to compose all the rules for a device.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you are using systemd, it's version of udev has a complex "persistent naming scheme" that's [hard coded into udevd](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/tree/src/udev/udev-builtin-net_id.c), so you are right, just parsing the `rules.d` stuff could leave a lot of mysteries.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you use:

```
udevadm monitor
```

you get an entry for each action taken by KERNEL and UDEV. Typically add, change, remove. If you include the `--property` option:

```
udevadm monitor --property
```

You will get a listing of what properties are used.

---

As one can test udev rules with udevadm:

```
udevadm test $(udevadm info -q path -n <device>)
```

one could test out something as this:

```
udevadm test $(udevadm info -q path -n <device>) 2>&1 | \
sed -n 's/.* \(\/[^ ]*\)\.rules:\([0-9]\+\)/\1.rules \2/p' | \
while read -r f n; do printf "%03d:%-50s " $n "$f"; sed -n ${n}p $f; done
```

but not sure how reliable this is. Anyhow, using e.g. `video1` for `<device>` that could yield something like:

```
031:/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules            SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux", GROUP="video"
007:/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-v4l.rules          IMPORT{program}="v4l_id $devnode"
009:/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-v4l.rules          SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", IMPORT{builtin}="usb_id"
010:/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-v4l.rules          KERNEL=="video*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="?*", SYMLINK+="v4l/by-id/$env{ID_BUS}-$env{ID_SERIAL}-video-index$attr{index}"
016:/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-v4l.rules          IMPORT{builtin}="path_id"
017:/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-v4l.rules          ENV{ID_PATH}=="?*", KERNEL=="video*|vbi*", SYMLINK+="v4l/by-path/$env{ID_PATH}-video-index$attr{index}"
015:/lib/udev/rules.d/73-seat-late.rules               TAG=="uaccess", ENV{MAJOR}!="", RUN{builtin}+="uaccess"
006:/etc/udev/rules.d/83-webcam.rules                  KERNEL=="video[0-9]", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0c45", SYMLINK+="video-webcam1"
```

But guess looking at the *test* as a whole is better. Also note the message:

> This program is for debugging only, it does not run any program
>   specified by a RUN key. It may show incorrect results, because
>   some values may be different, or not available at a simulation run.

---

You can also set

```
udev_log="debug"
```

in `udev.conf` and restart udev (`reload udev`) to get a somewhat more verbose output.