# how to find out if kernel or udev created a device node?

Tags: udev

Is there any way to find out who created a device node? If it has been `udev` or the kernel itself?

In the specific case of mine, I have two webcams. Nodes created for them are
`/dev/video0` and `/dev/video1`. Unfortunately this is not a constant assignment. Now I thought that would be the case when using `udev`, but when I create a `udev` rule it seems to me that `video0` and `video1` nodes are already created prior to `udev` being able to assign a more constant node like `/dev/videoLogitech`.

I need some suggestions regarding which log-file or which command might help me to find out about what happens here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to check order of actions use:

```
udevadm monitor --property
```

by doing this you get a listing of actions. When you add your camera one of the first entries is likely to be something like:

```
KERNEL[110935.814197] add      /devices/.../video4linux/video1 (video4linux)
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=/dev/video1  <<<<---- devname
```

As [pointed out by @goldilocks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182309/list-all-udev-rules-e-g-for-a-device#comment303553_182309):

> Unfortunately, if you are using systemd, it's version of udev has a complex "persistent naming scheme" that's [hard coded into udevd](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/tree/src/udev/udev-builtin-net_id.c), so you are right, just parsing the `rules.d` stuff could leave a lot of mysteries.

[Also from `man udev` for systemd:](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udev.html#NAME)

> The following keys can get values assigned:
>
> NAME
>   The name to use for a network interface. See systemd.link(5) for a higher-level mechanism for setting the interface name. ***The name of a device node cannot be changed by udev, only additional symlinks can be created.***

---

#### Naming and debugging

Your best option is likely to use something like:

```
udevadm test $(udevadm info -q path -n video1)
```

It gives you a "test run" on your rule(s) and report any errors.

After adding/changing a rule, remember to reload with:

```
udevadm control --reload-rules
```

When it comes to *naming* a devices you likely get something like:

```
NAME="smile2thecamera" ignored, kernel device nodes can not be renamed; 
      please fix it in /etc/udev/rules.d/83-webcam.rules:6
```

You could instead use a SYMLINK (if that suffice) as in:

```
KERNEL=="video[0-9]", .... SYMLINK+="video-logitech"
```

Should give you something like this on test:

```
creating link '/dev/video-logitech' to '/dev/video1'
creating symlink '/dev/video-logitech' to 'video1'

DEVLINKS=.... /dev/video-logitech
```

Comment: *"As for who named the device it is the kernel"* -- not necessarily, [see here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182309/list-all-udev-rules-e-g-for-a-device#comment303553_182309).  Symlinking sounds like the simplest solution anyway.